# physical location of informatica mongo DB Driver

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, driver, informatica

I am connecting my power BI to mongo db using Informatica mongo Db driver.we tried "mongo db odbc 1.4.3 ANSI driver" and "mongo Db odbc 1.4.3 unicode driver" but no luck.

Also i dont see this as a good practice to install informatica to get these drivers just to make powerbi talk to mongodb. so looking for a way to share this drivers to my team as that would suffice the need.

Can someone tell me how to find the physical location where I can find the informatica mongo db driver. If I go to my local odbc - DSN, I can find Informatica mongo db driver. But I could not find its location easily.

Comment: Have you tried using ODBC just as described at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/connect/powerbi/ ? Any issues with that one?

Comment: It requires the company information to be filled out to download the connector  which our company doesnt allow